# I am posting from angular2 to net core and getting: failed to load resource the server responded with a status code 415 (unsupported media type)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am posting stop object from angular2, this is the code

```
    addStop(stop: IStop):  Observable<IStop> {  

        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this._http.post(this._tripsUrl, stop, options)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
   }
```

this is net core code that should get the object but is not activated, 
when I remove [FromBody] attribute, the service activated- but I am getting null

```
    [Route("api/trips/{tripName}/stops")]
    [HttpPost("")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(string tripName, [FromBody]Stop theStop)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           //some code

            if (await _repository.SaveChangesAsync())
            {
                 return //some code
            }
        }
        return BadRequest("Bad Request");
    }
```

need help,  I am not finding the error

Comment: You don't need this **let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });**, by default http providers sends stringfyed JSON object. And looks like your are not passing something in the URL! Could you show the ***this._tripsUrl**?

Comment: Could you try removing the Route attribute from the action and just using `[HttpPost("api/trips/{tripName}/stops")]`? Because now it looks like there are two routes registered.

Comment: _tripsUrl is:
 private _tripsUrl = 'http://localhost:53620/api/trips/Berlin/stops';

Comment: I replaced the action as you say but still the same error

Answer (score 0):

It was cors issue, I already defined cors in my web.config of my ASP.NET Core  server, and get function worked OK, but the post function didn't work,  the right way to define cors is written in this article: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Sep/26/ASPNET-Core-and-CORS-Gotchas